# Contents or Images are not Displaying under Default Website IIS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-hosting

I have created a web Setup Project and after installing that web setup in local IIS following is the URL

```
http://localhost/testProject
```

But the problem is that all my content files are not shown.In `inspect element` of chrome URL generated for content files is

```
http://localhost/Content/images/bg-login-page.jpg
```

Path should be like this

```
http://localhost/testProject/Content/images/bg-login-page.jpg
```

My HTMl Img tag is

`<img src="/Content/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">`

Also if i move the website from default website to new website then it is working fine

**Question :** how to get content displayed for website placed under default website or outside

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `Url.Content` which will generate correct path for you:

`<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")" class="logo" alt="Logo">`

Comment: actually i want general solution bcoz application is ready and there are lots  of tags and ajax calls are also there. So is there any general solution for these

Comment: I have replaced code with `@Url.Content` but still not working

Comment: @Nilesh `Url.Content` should work. Content folder is in root directory of Application?

Comment: Folders are outside Content Folder

Comment: you have images folder inside content?

Comment: yes one is inside and other is outside both have different purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use MapPath :

```
string pathToFiles = Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles");
```

For more info : [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)